# Is there a way to make Citrix ICA files try multiple servers before giving up?

Tags: citrix

I have a Citrix ICA file that is connecting to a Citrix server.  I'm wondering if there is a way to put all the Citrix servers into the ICA file so that the Client tries different servers if it can't connect to the first one.

This is the line at the moment that handles what IP to connect to:

```
Address=server ip:server port
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is there no load balancer in this scenario?

Comment: Well, there might be. I'm trying to configure a computer to automatically connect to a Citrix server via an ICA file after the machine has booted up, automatically.  In some instances the server might be offline so I want to try the connection on a few servers before giving up :)

Answer (score 0):

No, because you're not meant to be using static ICA files - that's a huge huge hack. You should be brokering connections on demand using Citrix Web Interface or StoreFront. Yes, your users will prompted to login before hand but this ensures a proper distribution and control of where users end up.

I suppose in principle it might be possible to shove a load balancer in front of it but, well, don't.